# Javascript getElementById().value returns undefined on input elements

Tags: javascript, html, dom, input, undefined

I'm trying to make a small web application, and I need to get values from input elements and push them to an array a variable number of times.

The first time I do this it returns `undefined`, the second time it pushes the first value x1 and x2 amount of times, but not the second value.

`list` and `entree` are global variables.

`function winner()` does not yet get called.

And yes, I do enter something in both the inputs before pressing any buttons.

```js
var list = [];
var entree;

function addToList() {
  if (document.getElementById("Name")) {
    console.log("addToList triggered");
    entree = document.getElementById("Name").value
    for (i = 0; i < document.getElementById("Lose").value; i++) {
      list.push(entree);
    }
  }
}

function ausgeben() {
  for (j = 0; j < list.length; j++) {
    document.write(list[i] + " ");
  }
}
```

```html
<label for="Name">Name</label>
<br>
<input type="text" name="Name" id="Name" maxlength="30">
<br>
<label for="Lose">Lose        </label>
<br>
<input type="Int" name="Lose" id="Lose" maxlength="40">
<br>
<button type="reset">Eingaben zurücksetzen</button>
<br>
<button onclick="addToList()">Eingaben absenden</button>
<button onclick="winner()">Los Ziehen</button>
<button onclick="ausgeben()">ausgeben</button>
```

Comment: Try `console.log(typeof document.getElementById("Lose").value)`. What type does it output? What type would you need for the `for` loop?

Comment: `type="Int"` doesn't exist, it will be treated as `type="text"`

Comment: Or you can use `type="number"` which is an input type specifically designed for entering number values.

Comment: You shouldn't use `document.write()` after the page has been rendered. Display the output in a DIV, or use `console.log()` for debugging.

Comment: What do you mean by "first value" and "second value"?

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky it outputs the typeof as string

Comment: @feldmeister and what type would you need for the second part of the for loop?

Comment: @barmar I mean that I'll write something into the inputs once and ittl return as undefined, if i write something in them agian it'll return the total number of strings i want, but only the first string repeated.

Comment: @terrymorse why did you undo the stack snippet? It would have made it a lot easier on everyone had it been in runnable form

Comment: @user120242 Sorry, my mistake. I'll reinstate the snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You used `i` instead of `j` in your for loop, hence `undefined` since `list[undefined]===undefined`.

```js
var list=[], entree;
function addToList(){
    if(document.getElementById("Name")){
        console.log("addToList triggered");
        entree = document.getElementById("Name").value  
        for(i=0; i<document.getElementById("Lose").value; i++){
            list.push(entree);
        }
    }
}
function ausgeben(){
    for(j=0;j<list.length;j++){
    // you used i instead of j, hence "undefined"
        document.write(list[j] + " ");
    }
}
```

```html
<label for="Name">Name</label> 
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="Name" id="Name" maxlength="30">
    <br>
    <label for="Lose">Lose        </label>  
    <br>
    <input type="Int" name="Lose" id="Lose" maxlength="40">
    <br>
    <button type="reset">Eingaben zurücksetzen</button>


<br>
<button onclick="addToList()">Eingaben absenden</button>
<button onclick="winner()">Los Ziehen</button>
<button onclick="ausgeben()">ausgeben</button>
```

Comment: There's no point writing a full answer when the problem is just a variable typo.

Comment: thank you i dont know how I missed that one jeez